# PANDAS python referencing 2nd dataframe and group criteria to obtain value of new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

df1:

```
Item_No  Handling_code
    001          1
    002          1
    003          2
    004          1
    005          1
    006          1
    007          2
```

df2:

```
Item_NO   Group_code
    001       331
    002       332
    003       333
    004       333
    005       333
    006       331
    007       331
```

I would like to have the following output as new df:
First, Merge the two data frames.
Then create a new handling code based on the group code. That is to say, the ItemNo on it's own can have a code of 1, but if any item within that group has the handling code of 2, then all Item_Nos in that group are 2 in the NEW_handling_code column.

In this example anything with group code 331 or 333.

df3:

```
Item_No  Group_Code  Handling_Code  NEW_Handling_code
    001       331        1                 1
    002       332        1                 2
    003       333        2                 2
    004       333        1                 2
    005       333        1                 2
    006       331        1                 1
    007       331        2                 2
```

Comment: What have you tired so far? Paste some code. Merging the data frames can be used with `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: Are 1,2 only possible values of Handling code or you want to take the max of handling code for a group?

Comment: It can only be 1 or 2. Merging the data frames is simple enough, but i'd like to go down row by row to check if handling code =2 then check the rest of the series to see if another item_No with that same group code appears then create value as 2 for that Item No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the two dataframes, groupby `Group_code` and transform max on `Handling_code`

```
df3= df1.merge(df2, left_on='Item_No', right_on='Item_NO')
df3['NEW_Handling_code']=df3.groupby('Group_code')['Handling_code'].transform('max')
```

This will work even if you values other than 1,2 in handling code. Assuming you need to take max of it

Answer (score 0):

Try with `transform` after `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2)
out['new_cod'] = out.groupby('Group_Code')['Handling_Code'].transform('max')
```